# Redis exception StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException

Tags: redis

I am getting this exception. Any clue?

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException:
It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail.
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- Is Redis up and running? Try to connect to it using `redis-cli`.
- Is your connection settings to Redis right in your code (i.e. you're connecting to the right host and port...)?

The exception is quite expressive: `ConnectionMultiplexer` couldn't reach target Redis server.